# Conditional Entropy and Conditional Expectation of Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, information-theory

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.10311) and find the following inequality:
\begin{align}
I(X;\hat{X}) &= h(X) - h(X|\hat{X})\\
&\geq  h(X) - h(X-\mathbb E[X|\hat{X}])\\
&\cdots\cdots
\end{align}
where $I(X;\hat{X})$ is the mutual information, $h(X)$ is the differential entropy, and $X$ and $\hat{X}$ are two Gaussian random variables. I'm confused as to why the inequality holds and I didn't find relevant theorems in Information Theory textbook. Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Must be linked to two facts: 1) for joinlty Gaussian rvs, the conditional expectaton minimizes the variance of the prediction error https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/problem-with-proof-of-conditional-expectation-as-best-predictor 2) for a given variance, the gaussian maximizes the entropy

Comment: For any function of just $\hat{X},$ $h(X|\hat{X}) = h(X - f(\hat{X})|\hat{X})$: this follows because given $\hat{X}, f(\hat{X})$ is a constant, and differential entropy is invariant to translation of the random variable by a constant. Since conditioning reduces differential entropy, this gives $h(X - f(\hat{X})) \ge h(X|\hat{X})$. Finally recall that conditional expectation of $X$ with respect to $\hat{X}$ is a function of $\hat{X}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks! It makes sense.